# shouldChangeCharactersIn range function not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The code below works fine when I have used it with a view controller, though my current view controller has a header and text fields are in their and it doesn't bring up an error in the code though it has no effect; the function is never called?

Here is the code - first put the func in class ProfileEditor

```
class ProfileEditor: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, ProfileEditorHeaderDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    print("text field func called")

    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0

    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    var maxLength = 0
    if textField.isEqual(header.displayNameTextFeild) {
        maxLength = 13

    return newLength <= maxLength 
}
```

then I put the func in the delegate

```
 protocol ProfileEditorHeaderDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

 }

 class ProfileHeaderEditor: UICollectionViewCell {

    let displayNameTextField: UITextField = {
       let tf = UITextField()
       tf.placeholder = "Display name"
       tf.font?.withSize(10)
       tf.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       tf.textColor = UIColor.black
       tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect

       return tf
    }()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you assigned textField.delegate?

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: TextField.delegate = self

Comment: hi yerkebulan , im not sure what you mean though i edited my question and added more code , i've tried various things though none have worked hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should implement `UITextFieldDelegate` which contains method: `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

add this line where you create your `Cell`

```
profileHeaderEditor.displayNameTextField.delegate = self // add this
```

Comment: thanks ive done this and now i can't type text into the text field ?

Comment: `shouldChangeCharactersIn` working wrong that is your logical mistake somewhere inside method, check it again